# Pushing number of times a button is clicked to an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm

How can I push the result in display value to an empty array to store for me for later implementation? The code I'm working with below. have tried several things but still, I'm not getting it

```js
var fixedVal = 10;
var displayVal = 0;

document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (fixedVal > 0) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
        add();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Fixed value is now 0.";
    }
});

document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (fixedVal < 10) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
        subtract();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Fixed value is now 10.";
    }
});

function add() {
    fixedVal--;
    displayVal++;
    document.getElementById("fixedValue").innerHTML = `Fixed Value: ${fixedVal}`;
    document.getElementById("displayValue").value = displayVal;
}

function subtract() {
    fixedVal++;
    displayVal--;
    document.getElementById("fixedValue").innerHTML = `Fixed Value: ${fixedVal}`;
    document.getElementById("displayValue").value = displayVal;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="fixedValue">Fixed Value: 10</div>
    <input id="displayValue" value="0" disabled></input>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
        <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
    </div>

    <div id="error"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

The code I'm working with below.

Comment: How exactly are you wanting to use an array?

Answer (score 1):

Add additional buttons to push `displayVal` onto an array, and show the contents of the array.

```js
var fixedVal = 10;
var displayVal = 0;

var allNumbers = [];

function saveNum() {
  allNumbers.push(displayVal);
}

function showNumbers() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = allNumbers.join(", ");
}

document.getElementById("store").addEventListener("click", saveNum);
document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", showNumbers);

document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (fixedVal > 0) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
    add();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Fixed value is now 0.";
  }
});

document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (fixedVal < 10) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
    subtract();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Fixed value is now 10.";
  }
});

function add() {
  fixedVal--;
  displayVal++;
  document.getElementById("fixedValue").innerHTML = `Fixed Value: ${fixedVal}`;
  document.getElementById("displayValue").value = displayVal;
}

function subtract() {
  fixedVal++;
  displayVal--;
  document.getElementById("fixedValue").innerHTML = `Fixed Value: ${fixedVal}`;
  document.getElementById("displayValue").value = displayVal;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="fixedValue">Fixed Value: 10</div>
  <input id="displayValue" value="0" disabled></input>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
    <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
    <button id="store" type="button">Save</button>
    <button id="show" type="button">Show</button>
  </div>

  <div id="error"></div>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply push it.

```js
let valArray = [];

var displayVal = 0;

function pushCurrentValue() {
 valArray.push(displayVal);
}
```

Then insert `pushCurrentValue()` wherever in your code you want it to be saved.

You can always just insert `valArray.push(displayVal);` wherever in your code too.

Its up to you if you want to use a function, or the push itself. Personally Id use the push.

Comment: `pushCurrentValue()` doesn't take an argument

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, typo. Im typing this from my classroom computer in school. Its a crappy keyboard